# ISBN 13 java code

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class ISBN_13 {
    public static int checkDigit (String isbn12){
        int finaldigit = 0;

        int stringLength = isbn12.length();
        if (stringLength!=12){
            return -1;  
        }
        try {
            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x = x +1){
                if (x % 2 ==1)
                    finaldigit = finaldigit + 3*Character.getNumericValue(isbn12.charAt(x));
                else {
                    finaldigit = finaldigit + Character.getNumericValue(isbn12.charAt(x));

                }
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) { 
            return -1;
        }
        finaldigit = finaldigit % 10;
        return 10 - finaldigit; 
    }
}
```

When I run it through a program that checks me code (CodeJudge) It keeps on telling me runtime error, missing class isbn 13. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: no it should run fine.

Comment: http://ideone.com/RDJshV works there (and it calculated the right number as far as I can tell. The method name should not be `checkDigit` though since it's not checking). Does that site require a specific class name maybe? (a Class for ideone for example needs to be either not `public` or named `Main`).

Comment: Show us the error and stacktrace. "Keeps on telling me runtime error" is no help.